# Backbone & working with non-JSON data

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I have a static file that's just one date-time per line, e.g.:

```
2014-03-14T16:32
2014-03-15T13:04
2014-03-16T06:44
...
```

I want to use that as a read-only data source for a backbone collection. Obviously that's not in the expected format. I thought I could just use the parse method on my collection to just convert it into a proper array of objects. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be working.

First, if I don't override fetch, the parse method never gets called -- it goes into the error handler, though it's unlcear exactly why -- it's not actually throwing any errors. I'm guessing that's because it's expecting a different response type or something?

Second, if I override both the fetch & parse methods thus:

```
var MyColl = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel,
    url: 'date-list.txt',
    parse: function(data) {
        var result = _(data.split("\n")).compact().map(function(item, i) { 
            return { theDate: item, globalIndex: i };
        });
        return result;
    },
    fetch: function() {
        $.get(this.url, this.parse);
    }
});
```

it correctly goes into parse, and parse seems to build a valid object, but my collection has 0 models after the whole operation...

I suppose the collection is winding up empty because when I call parse, it's not part of the expected flow any more so nothing is done with the result. Any other ideas about how I can make fetch properly handle what the server is returning?

Obviously, I could make the server return JSON, or I could use my own fetching function outside of backbone, but I'm hoping there's a way to avoid those ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default fetch method assumes you will be returning JSON from the endpoint, which the collection will then instantiate a new model for each object in the array from the JSON data.

With your current override, you just need to just build an array of Backbone models in your parse method:

```
parse: function(data) {
  var model = this.model;
  var result = _(data.split("\n")).compact().map(function(item, i) { 
    return new model({ theDate: item, globalIndex: i });
  });

  return result;
},
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing. The parse method never gets called unless I override fetch. It goes into the error handler, but it's not clear why. (I should probably make that clearer in the description.)

Comment: Oh I just meant to say that I think you do have to follow the second approach of overriding both fetch and parse because fetch expects JSON. You only need to make the slight modification from your current code of returning `new model({ theDate: item, globalIndex: i })` (see above) so that the collection populates correctly.

Comment: Weird. I could have sworn that in the past in `Collection.fetch()` I returned an array of objects, rather than an array of models. That seems to work, though, thanks.

Comment: On second thought, that's still not working. I.e. c = new MyColl(); c.fetch(); console.log(c.length) => 0;

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not passing correct function to `$.get`, or, to be more precise, correct function but not bound to specific object instance. One idea is to try this:

```
$.get(this.url, _.bind(this.parse, this));
```

But now, as you said, nothing is done with the result of `parse` method, so you can add elements to collection like this:

```
parse: function(data) {
    var result = _(data.split("\n")).compact().map(function(item, i) { 
        return { theDate: item, globalIndex: i };
    });
    this.set(result);
}
```